# Laravel Download Database Tables in background

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ssh

I've created command in Laravel which download (copy) database's .sql files from staging server and paste it on production server (Requirement). I don't have SSH access to production server, So created route for that command and execute it from URL. Here are my code.

**Route**

```
Route::get('console/import_all',
    function () {
    Artisan::call('importDatabase:staging', ['tables' => 'all']);
});
```

**Command Function**

```
private function downloadFile($url, $path)
{
    sleep(5);
    return copy($url, $path);
}
```

Now there are approx 30+ files and some of them are more than 10MB in size. My command works fine from SSH (by admin) and from URL as well. But issue is when I hit command from URL, page keeps loading till all download finish. **Is there any way to execute this from background?** So if admin hit button from admin panel, s/he should not wait for all the time until coping all file finish and I can display message that **process has been start and you will notify once done.**

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides Queue for your use case.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues

run `php artisan make:job DownloadFile`

then call the artisan command in the generated class

```
/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    Artisan::call('importDatabase:staging', ['tables' => 'all']);
}
```

Then dispatch job on your Route

```
Route::get('console/import_all', function () {
    \App\Jobs\DownloadFile::dispatch();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @cwang, I'll try and let you know if I face any issue.

Comment: Facing error "Class 'DownloadFile' not found" Do I need to call class by something like this?     
$DownloadFile = App\Jobs\DownloadFile::handle();
$DownloadFile::dispatch();

Comment: Working fine with dispatch(new \App\Jobs\DownloadFile()); but how do I know that job executed successfully or not?

Comment: unlucky no javascript promise style callback here, you can either catch exceptions directly in the handle method, or register a [failed job event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs).